# Database error in model using Code Igniter

Tags: sql, database, codeigniter

Error:
(POST http://localhost/codeigniter/Purchase/transaction/update?id=7 500 (Internal Server Error)

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''supp_id2` = 
s.`supp_id` WHERE p.purch_id =' at line 1

SELECT p.*, s.supp_name FROM purchase as p LEFT JOIN supplier as s ON 
p.'supp_id2` = s.`supp_id` WHERE p.purch_id =

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/codeigniter/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

this is the Controller of my code, this is where the transaction is located at

```
function transaction($txn = null) {
    switch ($txn) {
        case 'list':

            $response['data']=$this->Purchase_model->get_all_purchase();
            echo json_encode($response);

        break;

        case 'create':
            $purchase = 
            array(
                'po_number' => $this->input->post('po_number'),
                'date' => $this->input->post('date'),
                'supp_id2' => $this->input->post('supp_id2'),
                'contact_person' => $this->input->post('contact_person'),
                'delivered_to' => $this->input->post('delivered_to'),
                'plu_number' => $this->input->post('plu_number'),
                'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
                'remarks' => $this->input->post('remarks'),
            );

            $insert = $this->Purchase_model->purchase_add($purchase);

            $resp['row_added'] = $this->Purchase_model->get_purchase($insert);
            $resp['title'] = 'Success!';
            $resp['stat'] = 'success';
            $resp['msg'] = 'Purchase Information successfully created.';


            echo json_encode($resp);
        break;

        case 'update':
            $data = 
            array(
                'po_number' => $this->input->post('po_number'),
                'date' => $this->input->post('date'),
                'supp_id2' => $this->input->post('supp_id2'),
                'contact_person' => $this->input->post('contact_person'),
                'delivered_to' => $this->input->post('delivered_to'),
                'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
                'plu_number' => $this->input->post('plu_number'),
                'remarks' => $this->input->post('remarks'),
            );
```

this is the purchase model I created

```
 public function get_purchase($purch_id)
 {
    $db = "SELECT p.*, s.supp_name FROM purchase as p LEFT JOIN supplier as 
 s ON p.'supp_id2` = s.`supp_id` WHERE p.purch_id = $purch_id ";
 return $this->db->query($db)->result();-
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->where('purch_id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->row();
}
```

if you need to see the other details please ask so a I can send it to the comment section or edit this post, how to solve this?

**UPDATE:**

I changed the 'supp_id2`to`supp_id2` and it shows a new but I think the same error:

```
 Error Number: 1064

 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
 your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

 SELECT p.*, s.supp_name FROM purchase as p LEFT JOIN supplier as s ON 
 p.`supp_id2` = s.`supp_id` WHERE p.purch_id =

 Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/codeigniter/system/database/DB_driver.php

 Line Number: 691
```

Comment: Show purchase model in post and reference the line or function in which the error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is wron:

```
 $db = "SELECT p.*, s.supp_name FROM purchase as p LEFT JOIN supplier as 
    s ON p.'supp_id2` = s.`supp_id` WHERE p.purch_id = $purch_id ";
```

copy this select

```
  $db = "SELECT p.*, s.supp_name FROM purchase as p LEFT JOIN supplier as 
 s ON p.`supp_id2` = s.`supp_id` WHERE p.purch_id = $purch_id ";
```

Comment: Have you tried running the query on phpmyadmin or workbench?  Maybe you get more information

Comment: this is the result in the workbench:                                                        `11:15:03 $db = "SELECT p.*, s.supp_name FROM purchase as p LEFT JOIN supplier as s ON p.`supp_id2` = s.`supp_id` WHERE p.purch_id = $purch_id " Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$db = "SELECT p.*, s.supp_name FROM purchase as p LEFT JOIN supplier as s ON p.`' at line 1 0.032 sec `

Answer (score 0):

As you can see at the error

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''supp_id2` = 
s.`supp_id` WHERE p.purch_id =' at line 1

SELECT p.*, s.supp_name FROM purchase as p LEFT JOIN supplier as s ON 
p.'supp_id2` = s.`supp_id` WHERE p.purch_id =

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/codeigniter/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

Purchase id is not passing to the query.

Comment: what does it mean ?

Comment: that means p.purch_id = '3' here in your query purch_id is not passing which results in p.purch_id = this results in db error. make sure purch_id will not be null

Comment: copy and paste this query and try   $db = "SELECT p.*, s.supp_name FROM purchase as p LEFT JOIN supplier as 
 s ON p.supp_id2 = s.supp_id WHERE p.purch_id = $purch_id ";

Comment: I did that sir and it shows an error:                                                           `A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

SELECT p.*, s.supp_name FROM purchase as p LEFT JOIN supplier as s ON p.supp_id2 = s.supp_id WHERE p.purch_id =

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/codeigniter/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691`

Comment: hard code purchase id (2 or 3) to known values in db. if you get result then problem lies in values not passing propoerly